# How to specify a specific StepDefinitions file for a Cucumber (.feature) file

Tags: java, cucumber, bdd, gherkin

I'm doing some tests with cucumber, currently I have two .feature files, one for login and one for registration) and a StepDefinitions file for each .feature file.

Each StepDefinitions file has a @Before method, so I can do some settings before starting the tests.

The problem is that when I run all the login tests both the @Before specified for the login test and the @Before that I specified in the test for registration.

***Cucumber file (test for registration):***

```
Feature: Sign up
As a user
I want to create a new account
So that I can use the application

  Background:
    Given I am on the sign up page

  Scenario Outline: User can create a new account
    When I fill name with "<first_name>"
    And I fill lastname with "<last_name>"
    And I fill email with "<email>"
    And I fill password with "<password>"
    And I fill password confirmation with "<password_confirmation>"
    When I click on Sign up
    Then I must be authenticated

    Examples:
      | first_name | last_name   | email                      | password  | password_confirmation |
      | Rita       | A. Cheatham | RitaACyheatham@armyspy.com | 123456789 | 123456789             |
```

***StepDefinitions for Cucumber file:***

```java
public class SignUpStepDefinitions {

    private SignUp signUp;

    @Before
    public void before() {
        signUp = new SignUp();
        signUp.beforeEach();
    }

   # Code continuation...
}
```

Comment: Step definitions and hooks are not coupled to a feature file. Rather they are global. You can use every step definition and hook in every scenario.

Answer (score 1):

**Option 1**

This is a bad practice to have different implementations for the same step. To have things properly arranged you can use conditional hooks. So that you tag your feature in one feature file as say `@mytag1` and feature in another feature file with `@mytag2`.

Now you can distinguish `Before` hook for both the cases like:

```java
@Before("@mytag1")
public void before1() {
    // Some logic
}

@Before("@mytag2")
public void before2() {
    // Some different logic
}
```

> **P.S.** - Avoid using `@Before` wherever possible because it hides test logic from a person who just analyses the gherkin script

**Option 2**

Do not use `@Before` at all but make use power of `Background` so that you have different set up for both your cases. Use different step sytax where the actual actions are different

**Option 3**

The last and less desirable option is to to what you are particulary asking. When Cucumber glues everything together (having no explisit setup) it uses package structure to distinguish what is glued to what.

Say you have feature files like this:

```
Feature: my feature1

Scenario: test
  When doing a step
```

and

```
Feature: my feature2

Scenario: test
  When doing a step
```

Now. You can have different implementation for `When doing a step` if you have the class/package structure like this:

```
rootpkg
 somepkg1
  TestRunnerClass1
  somepkg2
   StepDef1
 somepkg3
  TestRunnerClass2
  somepkg4
   StepDef2
```

And also you have the following resource structure:

```
rootpkg/somepkg1/somepkg2/myfeature1.feature
rootpkg/somepkg3/somepkg4/myfeature2.feature
```

So once you are running `mvn test` it picks both test runners and since each in isolated package "branch" it would use different step definition implmentation.

Comment: I'm using before to do this.webDriver.manage().window().maximize(); and after to do this.webDriver.quit();. Where would you recommend I put these snippets if not in @Before and @After?

Comment: You can inject your driver to stepdef class and having that lazy initialized you can set up all that stuff within the logic creating your driver. Like shown here https://webelement.click/en/page_object_model_selenium_cucumber_guice